# Why does Cases not find a match to the pattern using ^n_. when n is a number other than 1?

Tags: pattern-matching

I am not good in patterns in Mathematica, and so can't figure what I am doing wrong.

This example works, when the exponent is `1`

```
ClearAll[y,x,n]
Cases[{( y[x]/x)^1}, (y[x]/x )^(n_.) :> n]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But when exponent is `2` it does not find it

```
 Cases[{( y[x]/x)^2}, (y[x]/x )^(n_.) :> n]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Help says

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I think this happens, because the font end changes `(y[x]/x)^2` to `y[x]^2/x^2` before `Cases`  gets hold of it? So the pattern is lost. But when I tried

```
   Cases[{( y[x]/x)^2}, (y[x]^n_.)/(x^n_.):>n]
```

It still returned `{}`

What is the correct way to handle this? I need to find all powers of expressions of form `y[x]/x`

Tried `HoldForm` and `Verbatim` and `Inactive` but can't get it to work.

---

**Addition**
This is really an observation and some rambling on my part about this issue. Did not want to put it as comment.

Answer by m_goldberg explains the problem (which comes down to knowing how Mathematica internally layout this expression, i.e. FullForm basically).

But When the exponent is a symbol, then it behaves differently

```
 Cases[{(y[x]/x)^a},(y[x]/x)^(n_):>n]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is because of the difference in FullForm between

```
 FullForm[(y[x]/x)^a]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 FullForm[(y[x]/x)^2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I would have expected then when the exponent is `a`, the FullForm should similar to when the exponent is a number, i.e. as follows

```
 Times[Power[x,-a],Power[y[x],a]]
```

Or

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So my lesson for the day, when using pattern in Mathematica, I need to look at FullForm to get the pattern right because what I see might not be what I think it is.

Comment: try `Cases[{(y[x]/x)^3}, Times[Power[x_, b_], Power[y_, c_]] :> Abs[b]]`

Comment: @Alucard Yes, using full form like this always works. But the question is, why `Cases[{( y[x]/x)^2}, (y[x]/x )^(n_.) :> n]` does not? I am writing the pattern as the expression appears.  Also help says `x^n_.` should match. I guess the question becomes, when should one use the `FullForm` for the pattern, vs. the "form" that appears on the screen that one is looking at. This is the confusing part about patterns in Mathematica.

Comment: Interesting question.  To what part of Help at you referring?

Comment: @bbgodfrey this is a screen shot I took from some WRI help pages long time ago. I do not know from which document or web page it came from. But I kept this screen shot  in my Mathematica cheat sheet [here](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/faq/mma_notes/MMA.htm#x1-13900091) for reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps

```
 Cases[{(...}, y[x]^(m_.) x^(n_.) /; m === -n :> m]
```

is what you are looking for. It returns `{2}` from

```
Cases[{(y[x]/x)^2}, y[x]^(m_.) x^(n_.) /; m === -n :> m]
Cases[{y[x]^2/x^2}, y[x]^(m_.) x^(n_.) /; m === -n :> m]
```

but returns `{}` from

```
Cases[{y[x]^2/x^3}, y[x]^(m_.) x^(n_.) /; m === -n :> m]
Cases[{y[x]^3/x^2}, y[x]^(m_.) x^(n_.) /; m === -n :> m]
```

The problem arises because, internally, Mathematica sees the exponent of `y[x]` and `x` as different integers (2 and -2) and it is necessary to inform it that one of the integers must be the negative of the other.